# Creating a snapshot including description via AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

This is my code for creating a snapshot via AWS Lambda.

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime

ec = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reservations = ec.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['Backup', 'backup']},
        ]
    ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )

    instances = sum(
        [
            [i for i in r['Instances']]
            for r in reservations
        ], [])

    print "Found %d instances that need backing up" % len(instances)

    to_tag = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for instance in instances:
        try:
            retention_days = [
                int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
                if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
        except IndexError:
            retention_days = 14

        for volume in ec.volumes.filter(Filters=[
            {'Name': 'attachment.instance-id', 'Values': [instance.id]}
        ]):
            description = 'scheduled-%s.%s-%s' % (instance_name, volume.volume_id, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))

            print 'description: %s' % (description)

        for dev in instance['BlockDeviceMappings']:
            if dev.get('Ebs', None) is None:
                continue
            vol_id = dev['Ebs']['VolumeId']
            print "Found EBS volume %s on instance %s" % (
            vol_id, instance['InstanceId'])

            snap = ec.create_snapshot(
                VolumeId=vol_id,
            )

            to_tag[retention_days].append(snap['SnapshotId'])

            print "Retaining snapshot %s of volume %s from instance %s for %d days" % (
                snap['SnapshotId'],
                vol_id,
                instance['InstanceId'],
                retention_days,
            )


    for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
        delete_date = datetime.date.today() +     datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
        delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print "Will delete %d snapshots on %s" % (len(to_tag[retention_days]), delete_fmt)
        ec.create_tags(
            Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
            Tags=[
                {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
            ]
        )
```

I got the following response :

```
'EC2' object has no attribute 'volumes': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 34, in lambda_handler
    for volume in ec.volumes.filter(Filters=[
AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'volumes'
```

Whgen I used ***ec = boto3.resource('ec2')*** instead of ***ec = boto3.client('ec2')***, I get the description but some others such as ***describe_instances don't work***

So, please tell me what the replacement for ***volumes*** is in *boto3.client('ec2')*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found these guys solutions to be the best to date:

https://blog.powerupcloud.com/2016/02/15/automate-ebs-snapshots-using-lambda-function/

There are examples of descriptions in their code base being added to snaps.

Comment: This satisfied my requirement. Thank you

Comment: This link is dead

Answer (score 1):

`boto3.resource` is an abstraction for low level `boto3.client` You are mixing both. If you are using `client.describe_instances`, then use `client.describe_volumes`.

If you want to use `resource.volumes`, then use `resource.instances`. I prefer `resource.instances` because of its powerful filter and abstraction. If you use resources and want to access the underlying client for some reason, you can get the low level client using `meta`.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = ec2.meta.client
```

Avoid dealing with reservations etc., Use `resource.instances`. There are plenty of examples if you google for it. Few lines of code and very readable.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. All I have to do now is add a description to the snapshot. Could you please tell me how to add that without changing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in my case I needed to copy all the tags from the EC2 instance to the snapshots, take a look to my code it might help you or at leas guide you:

https://github.com/christianhxc/aws-lambda-automated-snapshots/blob/master/src/schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups.py

Doing it this way, you just need to make sure that the instance has the "Name" tag so it can be copied to the snapshot, I also needed this because of the CostCenter tag

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution online https://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups/ did not fit my needs so I've written the following backup script. This is still my first draft but I find it's much easier to read and also a better implementation for me because rather than targeting instances, I target volumes. Tagging is also improved.

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime
import os

ec = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
TAG = os.environ['TAG']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    volumes = ec.describe_volumes(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': [ "Backup", TAG ]},
            {'Name': 'status', 'Values': [ "in-use" ] },
        ]
    ).get(
        'Volumes', []
    )

    print "Found {0} volumes that need backing up".format(len(volumes))

    for v in volumes:
      vol_id = v['VolumeId']
      print(vol_id)
      vol_name = None
      snap = None
      vol_tags = v.get('Tags', None)

      try:
          retention_days = [
              int(t.get('Value')) for t in vol_tags
              if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
      except IndexError:
          retention_days = 7

      delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
      delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      print "Will delete volume: {0} on {1}".format(vol_id, delete_fmt)

      if vol_tags is not None:
        for tag in vol_tags:
          try:
            if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
              vol_name = tag.get('Value')

              print(vol_name)
              snap = ec.create_snapshot(
                  VolumeId=vol_id,
              )

              ec2.Snapshot(id=snap['SnapshotId']).create_tags(
                  Tags=[
                      {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
                      {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': vol_name},
                  ]
              )

              break
          except:
            print "No Tag key 'Name' found."

        print "Retaining snapshot %s of volume %s aka %s for %d days" % (
            snap['SnapshotId'],
            vol_id,
            vol_name,
            retention_days,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the function and find description in the code and replace it with your custom description in single quotes.

Hope it helps!

```
#Tag to folllow
#Retention    number of days here
#backup
#backup-monthly

import boto3
import collections
import datetime

ec = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reservations = ec.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['backup', 'Backup']},
            # Uncomment this line if need to take snaphsot of running instances only
            # {'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']},
        ]
    ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )

    instances = sum(
        [
            [i for i in r['Instances']]
            for r in reservations
        ], [])

    print "Found %d instances that need backing up" % len(instances)

    to_tag = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for instance in instances:
        try:
            retention_days = [
                int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
                if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
        except IndexError:
            retention_days = 7

        for dev in instance['BlockDeviceMappings']:
            if dev.get('Ebs', None) is None:
                continue
            vol_id = dev['Ebs']['VolumeId']
            print "Found EBS volume %s on instance %s" % (
                vol_id, instance['InstanceId'])

            instance_id = instance['InstanceId']

            snapshot_name = 'N/A'
            if 'Tags' in instance:
                for tags in instance['Tags']:
                    if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
                        snapshot_name = tags["Value"]

            print "Tagging snapshot with Name: {} and Instance ID {}".format(snapshot_name, instance_id)

            snap = ec.create_snapshot(
                Description = 'Description goes here',
                VolumeId = vol_id,
                TagSpecifications = [{
                    'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
                    'Tags': [{
                        'Key': 'Name',
                        'Value': snapshot_name
                    }, ]
                }, ]
                # DryRun = False
                )

            to_tag[retention_days].append(snap['SnapshotId'])

            print "Retaining snapshot %s of volume %s from instance %s for %d days" % (
                snap['SnapshotId'],
                vol_id,
                instance['InstanceId'],
                retention_days,
            )


    for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
        delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
        delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print "Will delete %d snapshots on %s" % (len(to_tag[retention_days]), delete_fmt)
        ec.create_tags(
            Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
            Tags=[
                {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
            ]
        )
```